# Migrating from CRA to Vite breaks styles

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, create-react-app, vite

Im migrating my project from `CRA` to `Vite` and `Typescript`, it uses `Material UI` version 4 as component library. The problem is that now when I run the project the styles are not applied to the component, but if I press `cmd + s` on VS code in that component file, Vite reloads and now the style works. What can it be? I suppouse there is a configuration Im missing.

This is a component example with this behaviour:

```
import React from 'react'
import clsx from 'clsx'
import { Button as ButtonMaterial, CircularProgress } from '@material-ui/core'

import { sharedPalette } from '@support/theme-provider/themes/shared'
import useStyles from './Button.styles'

const Button = props => {
  const {
    className,
    children,
    color,
    disabled,
    href,
    onClick,
    loading,
    size,
    variant,
    loaderColor,
    ...rest
  } = props
  const classes = useStyles({ color, disabled, size, variant })

  return (
    <ButtonMaterial
      classes={{ root: clsx(classes.root, classes.themeColor) }}
      className={className}
      disabled={disabled || loading}
      href={href}
      onClick={onClick}
      size={size}
      variant={variant}
      {...rest}
    >
      {loading ? <CircularProgress size={20} style={{ color: loaderColor }} /> : children}
    </ButtonMaterial>
  )
}

export default Button
```

In this case neither the `classes` nor the `className` prop styles are applied to the component until I press save in the file and Vite reloads.

This is my `vite.config.ts`

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc'
import dns from 'dns'

dns.setDefaultResultOrder('verbatim')

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3000
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    esbuildOptions: {
      loader: {
        '.js': 'jsx',
      },
    },
  }
})
```

This is what it looked like previously, but now none of those styles are present in the element.
[image: Styles that are missing]

Comment: Should this include "ts" and "tsx" files too?

 ```optimizeDeps: {
    esbuildOptions: {
      loader: {
        '.js': 'jsx',
      },
    },```

Comment: I will add them, but was trying to migrate the components to ts one by one, so at this time all my files are jsx.. I dont have much experience with TS, can this be cause of that behaviour?

Comment: Do you mean that the component in which you are facing the issue is still a JSX file?

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked and didn't notice that all of the files are JSX now.
So, what you are trying to do is to ensure that vite does hot-reload when you make some changes to the component, without having to save it. Is it?
If my understanding is correct, vite refreshes the UI when it detects a change in the file, which happens when the file is saved to disk.
Were you able to get this to work when you were using CRA?

Comment: No, the problem is that when I start the develop service at first the styles of the component are not applied, but if I save the component file (even without any change) while the service is running, Vite do hot-reload and then the component style is applied

Comment: Also discovered that the app routing is not working, this two problems ocurrs when I run the command `vite` to serve in develop, `vite build` works fine

Comment: Do you have the code in github/sandbox? Will be good to take a look at tsconfig and package.json files.

Comment: Well, at the end it resulted that I had react 18 but react-dom 16, so after the migration need to update react-dom and react-router-dom that provoked some errors in StrictMode and here I am, fixing all incompatibilities I can find... thank you anyway

Comment: Good to hear that you figured it out